# GWT Super Devmode RPC fails, normal dev mode works

Tags: gwt, rpc, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am running Mac 10.8, with Juno, and GWTP.

When I use super dev mode: The console tells me this error.  I have applied all the suggestions in [GWT - occasional com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122798/gwt-occasional-com-google-gwt-user-client-rpc-serializationexception) .  When run this in Development mode I do not get this error and the code works as expected.

Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'xxx' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = xxx@37a9f449

After reading this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ZugfWpwnXJs/discussion am I running into a known problem and just have to wait for an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7522

See also: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/xQ2Fg0QARYs/discussion